# Measure as a slicer without calculated columns or calculated tables in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am struggling with setting a measure as a slicer while I cannot use calculated columns or calculated tables.
I have a table simply like this:

[image: source data table]

I have added two measures which give the count and the list of distinct Y for each X:

```
Distinct Y in each X - Count = 
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Table1[Y] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[X] )
)
```

and

```
Distinct Y in each X - List = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        CONCATENATEX ( 
            DISTINCT ( Table1[Y] ),
            Table1[Y], 
            ", "
        ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[X] )
    )
```

[image: output showing measures values]

Now what I need to have is:

1. the measure "Distinct Y in each X, Count" as a slicer
2. a visual table reacting to the slicer. This visual table contains only W and Z, something like below:

[image: required output]

I cannot use calculated columns or calculated tables. Do you know if this is possible with Power BI?

Many thanks

Comment: Why can't you use calculated tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a Measure in a Slicer, in  Power BI.

To achieve the functionality you require, you will have to use either a calculated column, or a calculated table.